# How can I use .startswith to replace the ENTIRE value of the cell instead of just the matching string?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to do something to the effect of this:

| Name | Status |
| --- | --- |
| Bill | Cancelled on 01/01/2023 |
| Jim | Active |
| Kim | Servicing |
| Rod | Cancelled on 05/01/1999 |
| Tii | Active |
| Meg | Cancelled without cause |

```
DF2= DF1.withColumn("status", when(DF1.status.startswith("Cancelled"), replace(DF1.status, "Eliminate")).otherwise(DF1.status))
```

| Name | Status |
| --- | --- |
| Bill | Eliminate |
| Jim | Active |
| Kim | Servicing |
| Rod | Eliminate |
| Tii | Active |
| Meg | Eliminate |

I'm not sure if what I wrote is right, but that end result is what I'm looking. I know `regexp_replace()` but that will only replace the word "cancel" and not the whole value. I know there has to be a quicker way than creating a UDF.

```
DF2= DF1.withColumn("status", when(DF1.status.startswith("Cancelled"), replace(DF1.status, "Eliminate")).otherwise(DF1.status))
```

(invalid syntax)

Answer (score 0):

The correct function is when, no need for replace.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when    
DF2= DF1.withColumn("status", when(DF1.Status.startswith("Cancelled"), "Eliminate").otherwise(DF1.Status))
```